# Creating and Linking a Database using Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, sequelpro

I am in the middle of transferring my website over to a Digital Ocean VPS from a Heart Internet reseller account but I am stuck on trying to get my old database to link to the new wordpress install. At the moment I am stuck on the following error;

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

What I have done is create a new database on my website through Sequel Pro then I imported the old database into this one. Following this I changed the DB_NAME / DM_USER to the name of the new database that I created. But I didn't change the DB_PASSWORD as I wasn't sure what this should be change too.

I have also noticed that the old DB is mentioning the old IP for the website a lot. Should I find and replace all these with my new IP?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right as you have moved to new host, the IP should be replaced to new IP and you also need to correctly update, DB username, password, Hostname once you extract the DB. If you still face DB password error one good way to reupdate the password.
Don't forget to add privileges to mysql user to get things working.